# How can I backup MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want to upgrade my MonoTouch installation from 3.2.6 to the latest 4.0.3 installation, but I'm tentative about it so I want to be able to safely go back to 3.2.6 in case things don't work out in 4.0.3. What's the best way to do this?

If I backup my /Developer/MonoTouch folder, install 4.0.3, and then restore my old /Developer/MonoTouch folder, will I have a happy 3.2.6 installation again?

Do I even need to bother with this? Can I instead just run the 3.2.6 installer again and that'll get me back to a happy 3.2.6 installation again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep your previous installer for 3.2.6 around.  If you want to go back to 3.2.6, you just install it again.

OS X is kind of dumb, there is no concept of uninstalling things.  You just install again over top of it.

PS - I would not even mess with it.  There were so many bugs in 4.0.3, I found it unusable.  You might also want to [read](http://tirania.org/blog/) up on it, but Novell has laid off most of the MonoTouch team.  Miguel de Icaza is starting [Xamarin](http://www.xamarin.com/) b/c of this, I believe.

Comment: Totally agree. MT 4 caused my app to crash in many places where it wasn't crashing when using MT 3.2.6. Still don't know why.

Comment: They added many changes to the compiler, and I believe they rushed to get MonoTouch 4 out the door a little too early.  See here for more info: http://monotouch.net/Releases/MonoTouch_4/MonoTouch_4.0.0

Comment: Can you detail some of the problems you've seen with 4.0.x? I've tested it on my app a couple times without problems, but I didn't do anything extensive. The big reason I want it is for the fixes to the [memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666905/monotouch-instability-continues-managed-memory-allocator-crashes) allocator [crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819700/why-is-our-monotouch-app-breaking-in-the-garbage-collector-it-is-not-out-of-memo). If I get those fixes, I can ship certain new features in my app.

Comment: Also, are these crashes in specific places that one can steer around, or are they general random crashiness all over the place? Have you guys used 4.0.3?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I always read their release notes when they come out. 

Mike, they are random crashes that are very difficult to reproduce with any normal frequency. See my original question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824059/why-does-monotouch-4-make-my-app-unstable-random-crashes-are-more-frequent). It wasn't ever fully resolved.

Comment: I found the async methods of HttpWebRequest were broken. Here is a bug report I filed: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=687865  This made my app unuseable, since we are using a shared library from the desktop that we always use for server interactions.